# How to load a long list of items and search it in React Native?

Tags: list, react-native, search, react-native-flatlist

I need to show a big catalog of goods.
Goods are loaded from REST API.
How it should be done?

1. **Loading:** Should I load a small amount of goods each time user scrolls to bottom of screen, then I save everything to redux?
2. **Filtering:** How should I filter that list by a keyword? Should this functionality be realized on server side or do I need to load all items of category to redux store and filter it there? Should I somehow cache the whole list of items after I load it?

What is logic for actions above?

Comment: Ok so I assume when you say load you are worried about rendering performance, in that case you dont need to save it in redux, simply use a FlatList which loads a certain number of items at a time and recycles the views once the user scrolls. And for search all you would have to do is filter your dataset and pass the new dataset to the FlatList and that should take care of it.

Comment: Filtering server-side is really your only option if your list of items is so large that it can't be loaded in one go.